# Alter exposed form not working with AJAX

Tags: 8, views

I have the same problem like this [View exposed filter block no alter form with ajax](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194561/view-exposed-filter-block-no-alter-form-with-ajax) but for Drupal 8.

I have form alter where I change exposed filter label and some options in the select box, but when I choose some option that is submitted with auto submit and works with AJAX, form alter is not called and I get old label and options for the filter.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:
I think that is working now. This comment pointed me in wrong (maybe?) direction: https://api.drupal.org/comment/61807#comment-61807

I've been using mymodule.view_execution.inc file and functions for my views are executed on first page load but later mostly ignored.

Now I moved that code to mytheme.theme file and it seems ok for now.

Comment: could you share the code that you have  tried so far?

Comment: `function mymodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
  if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-press-releases-block-1') {
    $form['field_date_value']['#options']['All'] = t('All Years');
  }
}`

It's working now. But if you add it to mymodule.view_execution.inc then it's not working always. So I moved it in mytheme.theme and it's working fine now.

Comment: This only works on the first page load, values return to default after every ajax call.